# Delete certain - priorly unknown - part of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

```js
/**
 * Created by Malal91 and Haziel
 * Select multiple email by jquery.email_multiple
 * **/

(function($){

    $.fn.email_multiple = function(options) {

        let defaults = {
            reset: false,
            fill: false,
            data: null
        };

        let settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
        let email = "";

        return this.each(function()
        {
            $(this).after(
                "<div class=\"all-mail\"></div>\n" +
                "<input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" class=\"enter-mail-id\" placeholder=\"Enter Email ...\" />"
            );
            let $orig = $(this);
            let $element = $('.enter-mail-id');
            $element.keydown(function (e) {
                $element.css('border', '');
                if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32) {
                    let getValue = $element.val();
                    if (/^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/.test(getValue)){
                        $('.all-mail').append('<span class="email-ids">' + getValue + '<span class="cancel-email">x</span></span>');
                        $(".cancel-email").attr("id", getValue);
                        $element.val('');

                        email += getValue + ','
                    } else {
                        $element.css('border', '1px solid red')
                    }
                }

                $orig.val(email.slice(0, -1))
            });

            $(document).on('click','.cancel-email',function(){
                //crucial part
                var valueToDelete = $(this).attr('id');
                //alert(valueToDelete);
                var current_value = $('#employee_email').val();
                var new_value = current_value.replace(valueToDelete, '');
                $('#employee_email').val(new_value);
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });

            if(settings.data){
                $.each(settings.data, function (x, y) {
                    if (/^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/.test(y)){
                        $('.all-mail').append('<span class="email-ids">' + y + '<span class="cancel-email">x</span></span>');
                        $element.val('');

                        email += y + ','
                    } else {
                        $element.css('border', '1px solid red')
                    }
                })

                $orig.val(email.slice(0, -1))
            }

            if(settings.reset){
                $('.email-ids').remove()
            }
            return $orig.show()
            //return $orig.hide()
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
span.email-ids {
    float: left;
    /* padding: 4px; */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
span.cancel-email {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 18px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 49%;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-top: 1px;    cursor: pointer;
}
.email-id-row {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.email-id-row input {
    border: 0; outline:0;
}
span.to-input {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 11px;
}
.email-id-row {
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    /*margin-top: 23px;*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>


<input class="input_link" id="employee_email" type="text" placeholder="test field - see result" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    //let user insert multiple emails
    $(document).ready(function($){
        let data = []
        $("#employee_email").email_multiple({
            data: data
        })
    });

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

I am currently facing some issues removing a certain part of a string of multiple emails. My current approach is to replace the value of the deleted email with an empty value; thus, I assigned each created delete button a unique id value in order to delete only this specific value. However, this does only work for the last inserted email.

The code is mainly from a js plugin which makes it easier to insert multiple emails in an input field (credits: [multiple email plugin Created by Malal91 and Haziel](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/email-multiple.html)).

Comment: can you provide your HTML ?

Comment: sure. I added a snippet. The upper input field is a control field. The lower one is the actual input